# How to get count of people based on age groups using SQL query in Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a following query (which a part of my actual query) which retrieves person_id and age for that person:

```
select p.person_id,TRUNC ((SYSDATE - p.birth_date) / 365.25, 0) AS age
from person p
```

Now after getting this age I want to get the number of people in each age group like:

```
 group                count
age <=5                100
age >5 and age <=10    50
 age > 10              15
   ...                ...
```

I can use group by clause to get count for individual age. But how to get count between two ages?

Can someone tell me the way in which I can do it?

you can use following data for your reference:

```
   pid    age
    1      4
    2      13
    3      10
    4      8
    5      9 
    6      12
```

So the result should be:

```
   group      count
   age < =5     1
   >5 & <=10    3
   > 10         2
```

Comment: Some sample data please? Either a sql fiddle or create and insert statements.

Comment: Sample data means simply i can give random person_id and age for that person. What else you need?

Comment: Sample data means post the data so that someone can use it to build the query. Post few rows, i.e. create table and insert statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your age calculation is incorrect.  You almost certainly want to measure the months between the two dates rather than hoping that dividing by 365.25 is close enough

```
trunc( months_between( sysdate, p.birth_date )/ 12 )
```

Second, if you want to group by ranges, you just need to select the range in a `case` statement and group by that

```
SELECT (case when age <= 5
             then 'age <= 5'
             when age > 5 and age <= 10
             then 'age > 5 and age <= 10'
             else 'age > 10'
         end) bucket,
       count(*)
  FROM( SELECT trunc( months_between( sysdate, p.birth_date )/ 12 ) age
          FROM person p )
 GROUP BY (case when age <= 5
                then 'age <= 5'
                when age > 5 and age <= 10
                then 'age > 5 and age <= 10'
                else 'age > 10'
            end)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to do something like this:

```
with data as (
  select p.person_id,TRUNC ((SYSDATE - p.birth_date) / 365.25, 0) AS age
  from person p
)
select '30 or below' as stat, sum(case when age between 0 and 30 then 1 else 0 end) as count from data
union all
select '31 to 60' as stat, sum(case when age between 31 and 60 then 1 else 0 end) as count from data
union all
select '31 to 130' as stat, sum(case when age between 31 and 130 then 1 else 0 end) as count from data
;
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c9ae4/13

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you already have calculated values for age. You could use **CASE** expression and **GROUP BY** different age groups.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH data(person_id, age) AS(
  2  SELECT 1,  3 FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2,  4 FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 3,  8 FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 4,  9 FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 5, 15 FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 6, 25 FROM dual UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 7, 32 FROM dual UNION ALL
  9  SELECT 8, 44 FROM dual UNION ALL
 10  SELECT 9, 67 FROM dual UNION ALL
 11  SELECT 10, 75 FROM dual
 12  )
 13  SELECT (
 14    CASE
 15      WHEN age <= 5
 16         THEN 'age <= 5'
 17      WHEN age > 5 AND age <= 10
 18         THEN 'age > 5 and age <= 10'
 19      WHEN age > 10 AND age <= 30
 20         THEN 'age > 10 and age <= 30'
 21      ELSE 'age > 30'
 22    END) age_group,
 23    COUNT(*)
 24  FROM data
 25  GROUP BY (
 26    CASE
 27      WHEN age <= 5
 28         THEN 'age <= 5'
 29      WHEN age > 5 AND age <= 10
 30         THEN 'age > 5 and age <= 10'
 31      WHEN age > 10 AND age <= 30
 32         THEN 'age > 10 and age <= 30'
 33      ELSE 'age > 30'
 34    END)
 35  /

AGE_GROUP                COUNT(*)
---------------------- ----------
age <= 5                        2
age > 10 and age <= 30          2
age > 5 and age <= 10           2
age > 30                        4

SQL>
```

If you don't have a range of age group, then you could use **DECODE** to hard code the exact age.